# How to account for radian to degrees inaccuracy

Tags: python, python-3.x, gis, geometry-surface

I am trying to perform a simple task using simple math in python and I suspect that the inherit error in converting from radians to degrees as a result of an error with floating point math (as garnered from another question on the topic please don't mark this as a duplicate question, it's not).

I am trying to extend a line by 500m. To do this I am taking the the endpoint coordinates from a supplied line and using the existing heading of said line to generate the coordinates of the point which is 500m in the same heading.

Heading is important in this case as it is the source of my error. Or so I suspect.

I use the following function to calculate the interior angle of my right angle triangle, built using the existing line, or in this case my hypotenuse:

```
def intangle(xypoints):
    angle = []
    for i in xypoints:
        x1 = i[0][0]
        x2 = i[1][0]
        y1 = i[0][1]
        y2 = i[1][1]
        gradient = (x1 - x2)/(y1-y2)
        radangle = math.atan(gradient)
        angle.append((math.degrees(radangle)))

    return angle
```

My input points are, for example:

```
(22732.23679147904, 6284399.7935522054)
(20848.591367954294, 6281677.926560438)
```

I know going into this that my angle is 35° as these coordinates are programmatically generated by a separate function and when plotted are out by around 3.75" for each KM. Another error as a result of converting radians to degrees but acceptable in its scope.

The error generated by the above function however, results in an angle that plots my new endpoint in such a place that the line is no longer perfectly straight when I connect the dots and I absolutely have to have a straight line.

How can I go about doing this differently to account for the floating point error? Is it even possible? If not, then what would be an acceptable method of extending my line by howevermany meters using euclidean geometry?

To add to this, I have already done all relevant geographic conversions and I am 100% sure that I am working on a 2D plane so the ellipsoid and such do not play a role in this at all.

Comment: Maybe using the `decimal` module would help: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/decimal.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using angles is unnecessary, and there are problems in the way you do it.   Using the `atan` will only give you angles between -pi/2 and pi/2, and you will get the same angle value for opposite directions.

You should rather use Thales:

```
import math

a = (22732.23679147904, 6284399.7935522054)
b = (20848.591367954294, 6281677.926560438)

def extend_line(a, b, length):
    """
    Returns the coordinates of point C at length beyond B in the direction of A->B"""
    ab = math.sqrt((a[0]-b[0])**2 + (a[1]-b[1])**2)
    coeff = (ab + length)/ab
    return (a[0] + coeff*(b[0]-a[0]), a[1] + coeff*(b[1]-a[1]) )

print(extend_line(a, b, 500))
# (20564.06031560228, 6281266.7792872535)
```

Comment: Thanks, Thierry. This is by far the most elegant solution I've come across without using the GDAL/OGR library, which I am trying to avoid.

However, this still introduces an error of around 5cm per KM. I know it seems like a little and I'm going to roll with it for now but its going to cause issue on longer lines.

Comment: What's the unit of your coordinates? 5 cm per km is a large error, and much more than what can be caused by rounding problems. What is the method you use to calculate the 'right' coordinates?

Comment: GOT IT! Without exhausting the issue any further my check data was quite simply flawed. I was using the original input data as a check and this was in geographic coordinates, prior to the conversion to a projected system, in a GIS package. That is where the 5cm comes from. Using your solution the error over 5km is 0.0000805um.